Why is $FP \subseteq \#P$?
Why is $FP \subseteq \#P$?
I've come across a number of sources that say the problem is trivial, but clearly I'm missing something.
For instance, the proof of lemma 8 in this lecture begins by assuming that a language ($\mathcal{L}$) is in $FP$. While the equivalence of the functions in $FP$ to the language associated with each bit of $f$ is established earlier in the lecture notes, one cannot say that the language is contained in $FP$. It is also not clear to me if this language $\mathcal{L}$ is the language associated with one of the bits of $f \in FP$. Hence, I am lost from the beginning of the proof, as $\mathcal{L}$ is not defined anywhere before this, nor is an equivalent language definition made. Any help understanding at least this initial statement in the proof of said lemma would be appreciated.

These lecture notes are full of typos. There should be no language $\mathcal L$ at all in the argument; just ignore it.
You simply have a function $f\in\mathsf{FP}$ computed by a DTM $M$, and you are proving that $f\in\#\mathsf P$ by constructing an NTM $N$ (renamed to $N'$ in the last two sentences for no apparent reason) whose number of accepting paths on input $x$ is $f(x)$. The rest of the construction works.
